# WordPress HTTPS redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

my host company activated on my page SSL certificate. In WordPress settings I changed the website URL from http://www.aden-reality.cz/ to https://www.aden-reality.cz/

Then I put into the htaccess:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

but still it shows me this error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Can you tell me how can I fixed? I tried many things. I used plugins for redirect, etc. nothing works.

Thanks for help

Comment: What if you comment your htaccess code? Does it still have error, I think https should work just fine without that tweak in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Is your company using Nginx or apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin in wordpress site so that you can easily get SSL installed

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Comment: Thank you. This plugin works, only the admin menu is not secured, do you have solution?

Comment: btw. in wp-config.php I have define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); but still not secured admin panel in WordPress

Comment: Please logout and relogin and check